# Set or add margin to left under each summary tag in html

Tags: css

Could someone help me to add a margin to left of "Second Summary" maybe 12px and to the "Third Summary" x2 or 24px?

I am thinking if it possible to use CSS selector.

```html
<details>
    <summary>First Summary</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Second Summary</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>Third Summary</summary>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
details details{
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want really only the sumamry:

details details summary {
    margin-left: 12px;
}

Comment: Answer could be improved with a short explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
details > details > summary
{
margin-left:12px
}

details > details > details > summary
{
margin-left:24px
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>First Summary</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Second Summary</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>Third Summary</summary>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use padding and it will work for any nesting level

```css
details details {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>First Summary</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Second Summary</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>Third Summary</summary>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
details > details {
 margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Every "details" inside an other "details" will get a left margin of 12px